# Convert released iPhone/iPad app to Universal

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

I have an app that has been released on the app store with separate versions for iPhone and iPad. Now I wish to convert the app to a Universal version but I have an issue which I'm not sure can be resolved.

Both versions of the app use a different bundle identifier (for example com.mycompany.app.iphone and com.mycompany.app.ipad). I want the new (universal) version to overwrite either of the old versions when downloaded from the app store. To complicate matters further, core data stored for that app needs to be retained.

I'm not sure its possible and perhaps the protocol is to release the universal version under a new bundle identifier and have users start again but if a workaround is available it would be really helpful.

Comment: any reason why you are not thinking of releasing the universal binary as an update to both the apps?

Comment: I wasn't aware that it was possible, will that not result in two different version still being on the app store?

Comment: I am assuming, your iPhone and iPad versions have different names/icons etc. I have never done this, but I dont see why it should not be possible. Since you are submitting both binaries with different bundleIDs, it should be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

your options:

```
1: Update both your iPhone and iPad apps with this universal binary (with respective bundleIDs and app names)
2: Create a way to sync data between apps by creating a web service. one of the apps I have used extensively - Gas Cubby, does this for transferring data from its free app to paid app. You could implement it in a similar way
3: Nuke one of the apps, update the other app with the universal binary
```

Option 1 is the easiest. 2 will take longer. 3 is dirty.

(will update this answer with more options if I come across any)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know and from what I've read before, you can't change the bundle identifier of an app published in the app store.

Due to the sandboxing, accessing the data of your old app from the new app is also impossible.

There are several ways you could go about solving this issue, depending on which one suits you best. You could create a new universal app, and abandon the old ones hoping that the users change their preferences, or you could be pushing the same update to both applications, essentially, having the identical app under two different names. I'm not sure what are Apple's stances on the second option, but it will be a hassle either way. Good luck!